# Angle between position/velocity vector and tangent vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

r(t) = (e^(t)cos(4t), e^(t)sin(4t))

Verify that the angle ψ between the position vector and tangent vector is constant, and find the angle.
[logarithmic spiral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGIJg.png)

so far, I have r'(t)= (e^(t)cos(4t) - 4e(t)sin(4t), e(t)sin(4t) + 4e^(t)cost(4t)) but I am not quite sure how to go about finding the angle and verifying that it is constant between the tangent and position vector.

Comment: You have $r(t)$ which is the position vector and $r'(t)$ which is the tangent vector. So you need to verify that $\frac{r'(t)\cdot r(t)}{\|r(t)\|\|r'(t)\|}=c$, which would imply the angle is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v = r' = (e^t\cos 4 t - 4e^t\sin 4t, e^t\sin 4t + e^t\cos 4t)$

And this can be broken into components that are circular and centrifugal

$v = r + 4r^\bot\\
r\cdot v = \|r\|^2$

and

$r\cdot v =\|r\| =  \|r\|\|v\| \cos \theta \\
\cos\theta =\frac {\|r\|}{\|v\|} = \frac {1}{\sqrt {17}}$